# VUA and AUTH0 is not landing on previous URL after login

Tags: vue.js, auth0

I've been folowing the guide [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/01-login#configure-auth0). It works, the only problem is, when I click on login from:

```
http://localhost:8082/1#/
```

Then I'm redirected back to something like: `http://localhost:8082/?code=Ws1cWuAuEK6QpFPz&state=LTFLVmZjWGhrSWl3aFhrM3I4N0xSQUJqaFB1M0NhTEtxUElVSkxQOXZXUg%3D%3D#/`

While I want to have exactly the same URL in browser as before login.

How to get it?
Idealy some link to guide, as I'm very new to VUE and AUTH0.

EDIT:
I need to not to use mode:history in src/router/index.js As I'am using the url as a path variable for my backend.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how `auth0` works with vue but I'm sure you can do something like on created method `this.$router.push({ name: 'login' })` which will get rid of all of your parameters on the URL

Comment: Thanks fro reply. It's not only about parameters. It's missing the path variable 1 from origin URL as well.